# Check a string regardless of case structure

Tags: php

I have this code that checks if a string is blue.
I want it to approve it regardless of whether it's lower or upper case in any of the letters.

```
if( ($subcol !== 'blue') || ($subcol !== 'Blue') || ($subcol !== 'BLUE')    ) {
    $form->setError($field, "* Colour not correct, use the hint");
}
```

This doesn't seem to work?
Have I structured something wrong?

Also, is there a PHP function that can be used that will just check it once for all these scenarios?

Thanks

Comment: *"If it's NOT 'blue' OR NOT 'Blue' OR NOT ..."* It can't be *all* of it, so at least one of these conditions is always true.

Comment: This is a mistake I make when I haven't used operators for some time. They should be && not ||. Thanks bud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
if (strcasecmp($subcol, 'blue') === 0)  {
```

This is true for `blue` `BLUE` `Blue` `bLue` etc.

Comment: That is exactly the function I was after! I just couldn't remember what it was called or find an effective google search!

Answer (score 0):

Or..

use this [strtoupper](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php)

i.e.

```
if ('BLUE' == strtoupper($subcol)) ....
```

Comment: @Baba - It will convert all the characters to upper case. Hence the comparison will work if it is any combination of upper and lower case characters as you are comparing with a string in upper case. I would also like to add that this could be a one off event if you need to compare with other colours in the proceeding code.

Comment: `if ('BLUE' === strtoupper($subcol))` is more correct. You can also use `strtolower` of course.

Comment: `toupper` is `c++` not PHP ... it should be `strtoupper`

Comment: Sorry about that. But you can do this use `strtoupper` on that string ant then use a case statement.